# Crawler4j Stops Silently

Tags: java, web-crawler, crawler4j

In my application,I am using crawler4j. Though application is big, but I have even tested code with sample codes given here : https://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/source/browse/src/test/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/examples/basic/

Problem is, it works for most of the sites, but when I add seed url as : http://indianexpress.com/ , the crawler stops without any error message on my eclipse. I tried  several times, but it just doesn't work. I tried printing url and sample text like "hello" in shouldVisit method, but nothing prints means it is not reaching even there. What could be the issue ?

Edit :

I just figured, crawler4j is not working for any wordpress site. For instance, http://darcyconroy.net/ or you can check http://indianexpress.com/next (add /next to any wordpress site url) . What could be the reason ? http://indianexpress.com/robots.txt doesn't seem to have any dubious thing written.

Comment: Have you checked that it allows crawling with robots.txt

Comment: yes it allows. and problem is with only one site so far.

Answer (score 1):

I think, the wordpress site has some plugins to filter Useragents other than just robots.txt.

I can say the crawling is blocked by the server.

Enable Logger output.

BasicConfigurator.configure();

Set Logger to WARN Level.

Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.WARN);

Change the UserAgent String to Empty with below code, it crawl the data.

config.setUserAgentString("");

So i think its nothing to do with crawler4j. Crawler4j sets the default Useragent string, which i think blocked or its useragent string is blacklisted by such plugins.